# Google App Engine Manual Scaling Prevents Restart

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud

I have a python app engine that handles api results and it's stateful. However it seems that after a few hours of inactivity (no requests), the server shuts off, resetting all states, and when a new request is made, it's listening again.
But the states are reset. I want the server to actively remain unchanged 24/7 and not reset/restart as I want to maintain states.

I have configured as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref) but it's still restarting, I am not sure what's wrong

Here is my app.yaml:

```
runtime: python37
entrypoint: python main.py
manual_scaling:
instances: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In App Engine the general recomendation is to create stateless applications as mentioned on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-instances-are-managed)

> Your app should be "stateless" so that nothing is stored on the instance.

As an alternative for the application not to get restarted you can deploy it on Compute Engine, As that service is a Virtual Machine you can have total control of the states.